# Moving underglow on a Bootstrap Navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

First question on Stackoverflow but I've used it constantly while learning how to make websites and a bunch of other stuff. I've been using Bootstrap to create a website with a friend and in the past we've both seen websites with really beautiful navbars.

What we're wondering is if we can utilise Bootstrap's navbars and add some additional code to add a sort of under-glow to the buttons! In an ideal world too, this glow would move from button to button following the cursor and reset to the currently active page button if none are hovered over. I'm hoping you've seen something like this before but it's actually difficult for me to find an example of this now.

I've been looking at using this sort of effect but turned upside down

```css
body { margin: 30px; }


hr {
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    height: 5px;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 0%, 50% 5px, #aaa 0%, white 100%);
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

(Source: http://jsfiddle.net/sonic1980/65Hfc/; (provided by another amazing stackoverflow user))

Is this possible? Thanks for any help, let me know if I can provide any further information.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate it with a box shadow, check it out:

```
.btn{
     box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #888888;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gumxt15q/

Using inset

http://jsfiddle.net/q0ere00q/

Comment: Thanks for the response! Actually we were hoping we could use the "shadow effect" upwards inside the button as a sort of glow! Here's an example of a similar effect but done using photoshop: http://smashinghub.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/171.jpg

Comment: See edit above, all it took was googling "box shadow outer and inner"